# Can somebody explain the Output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
q =["hello", "there"]
q.insert(2,"How r u")
print("Result : "),q
```

OUTPUT:

> Result :
>
> (None, ['hello', 'there', 'How r u'])

Why it prints `None`?

Comment: Because `print` returns `None`.

Comment: Because your in a notebook last line == to: print(print("Result : "),q)

Comment: Any function in python that not explicitly returns _something_ returns `None` implicitly. I however can not reproduce your output, neither 2.7 nor 3.x in http://www.pyfiddle.io produces _your_ output.

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `print` returns `None`.

For **example**:

```
>>> print(print(1))
1
None
```

First it prints value and then returns `None`.

**Explaining your code**:

```
q =["hello", "there"]
q.insert(2,"How r u")
print(print("Result : "),q)
```

**Steps**:

Start from inner `print`:

```
print("Result : ") # -> prints Result :  and returns None
```

Now it becomes:

```
print(None, q) # -> prints None ['hello', 'there', 'How r u']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Result : "),q
```

should be

`print("Result : ", q)`

Comment: I know that but can u please tell me why it prints "none" .

Answer (score 0):

Every list of var names in python are in reality a tuple, so:

`a, b` is really `(a, b)`

so

`print("Result : "),q` is a tuple of values `(None, q)`